# RODBC (sometimes) does not read numbers

Tags: r, rodbc

I am reading Excel sheets into R using ROBDC. However, I encountered some strange results. Sometimes, restarting the R console will help, but I tried 3 times now, and the following bug (?) persists.

The Excel sheet contains blocks of numbers, which I want read into an array.

This is my sqlQuery:

```
channel <- odbcConnectExcel(paste("~link to file~"))
as.matrix(sqlQuery(channel,paste("select F13,F14,F15 from \"",land,i,"$\"",sep="")))
```

Here is (a part of) the result:

```
32 NA             NA             NA   
33 NA             NA             "Pf7"
34 "2.079975e+02" "6.762166e+01" NA   
35 "1.721265e+02" "5.595971e+01" NA   
36 "1.373673e+02" "4.465921e+01" NA   
37 "1.200835e+02" "3.904013e+01" NA   
38 "1.411489e+02" "4.588864e+01" NA   
39 NA             NA             NA   
40 NA             NA             NA   
41 NA             NA             NA   
42 NA             NA             "Pf7"
43 "1.443768e+00" "4.693807e-01" NA   
44 "1.194778e+00" "3.884318e-01" NA   
45 "9.535044e-01" "3.099920e-01" NA   
46 "8.335332e-01" "2.709883e-01" NA   
47 "9.797535e-01" "3.185257e-01" NA   
48 NA             NA             NA   
49 NA             NA             NA
```

In the Excel sheet, every block of numbers is preceded by Pf5:Pf7, and every description Pf5:Pf7 is followed by 5 numbers. All cells are formatted as number. The Excel sheet can be downloaded [here](http://www.wu.ac.at/usr/ma/mzuba/test2.zip).

In columns F13 and F14, RODBC drops the descriptions (which is strange but fine with me), in column F15 it drops the numbers (which is not fine with me at all!)

The strange thing is that exactly the same code worked just fine yesterday, and I did not update any R files or change the Excel sheets in any way, so I am puzzled regarding what might cause the error.

I am grateful for any comments that might help.

Thanks,
Martin

UPDATE:
I tried using odbcConnectExcel2007 instead of odbcConnectExcel, here are the results:

```
22 NA             NA             NA             
23 NA             NA             NA             
24 NA             NA             "Pf7"          
25 "7.730711e+01" "1.958429e+01" "12,638675305" 
26 "4.126044e+01" "1.045255e+01" "6,7455279987" 
27 "4.293419e+01" "1.087656e+01" "7,0191635751" 
28 "4.278764e+01" "1.083944e+01" "6,9952057822" 
29 "4.073317e+01" "1.031897e+01" "6,6593269202" 
30 NA             NA             NA             
31 NA             NA             NA             
32 NA             NA             NA             
33 NA             NA             "Pf7"          
34 "9.001111e+01" "2.280260e+01" "14,715610176" 
35 "4.804083e+01" "1.217023e+01" "7,854032014"  
36 "4.998963e+01" "1.266392e+01" "8,1726345871" 
37 "4.981901e+01" "1.262070e+01" "8,1447397695" 
38 "4.742692e+01" "1.201471e+01" "7,7536653665" 
39 NA             NA             NA             
40 NA             NA             NA
```

The "," instead of the "." could be caused by me using a German version of Excel. I could use sub() to replace the commas, but this (1) would not be an elegant solution, and (2) does not explain why it works with the first two cols but not with the third. (And also not why it worked yesterday but not today...)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the corresponding input to the results you show.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: I don't quite understand what you mean. The input that produces the result is two lines above the result, and the Excel sheet is described just below the results. If that is unclear, I could post a screenshot of the respective Excel sheet?

Comment: @mzuba: I'm referring to the input in your Excel file.  _Please_ don't post an image of your data, give us something we can copy/paste into an Excel file so we can try to replicate your problem.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: Alright, that makes sense. The Excel sheet is linked in the original question. Thank you for your effort. If you find out where the problem lies it would be cool, otherwise I'll use the workaround with `odbcConnectExcel2007`.

Comment: Do not use as.matrix, that will coerce all columns to one mode so you lose what the types of most columns were. Also read the vignette for RODBC for particular vagaries with Excel. And obviously compare with the actual data itself which we cannot

Comment: @mdsumner: What is the vignette of RODBC and how do I read it? Also, the relevant Excel sheet is linked in the question, but as Joshua cannot reproduce the error, there seems to be an other problem.

Comment: library(RODBC);vignette("RODBC")

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the Excel file.  Are the contents of the cell actually numbers?  (If you look in the formula bar, something like `'123` reveals the cell contents to be a string, not a number.)

You could also look into using, e.g., `read.xls` in the `xlsReadWrite` package.  It's a little simpler than having to use SQL queries.  (Likewise, `read.xlsx` in the `xlsx` package for Excel 2007 onwards.)

Comment: All numbers are numbers and not strings, which is strange, since RODBC reads them as strings (note the `"2.079975e+02"` in the result). I use `as.numeric()` later on.

While using the `xlsReadWrite` package might be an option, I’d prefer sticking with `RODBC`, since for some queries I use SQL functionality is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `as.matrix` for a dataframe that may have different column data types.

Your code is not self-contained, but it should be pretty obvious what is going on if you decompose your code into something understandable and reproducible.

Using the file "test2.xls" in the zip provided in the question:

```
library(RODBC)
d <- sqlQuery(con, "SELECT [F13], [F14], [F15] FROM [Wien2008$]")
con <- odbcConnectExcel("test2.xls")
summary(d)
    F13                 F14              F15    
Min.   :6.584e-01   Min.   :1.668e-01   Pf7 : 6  
1st Qu.:4.073e+01   1st Qu.:5.744e+00   NA's:61  
Median :7.731e+01   Median :1.262e+01            
Mean   :2.108e+03   Mean   :1.027e+04            
3rd Qu.:2.322e+02   3rd Qu.:4.738e+01            
Max.   :5.697e+04   Max.   :2.791e+05            
NA's   :3.000e+01   NA's   :3.400e+01
```

`F13` and `F14` look like numbers to me.

```
sapply(d, class)
     F13       F14       F15 
"numeric" "numeric"  "factor"
```

What happens if we trash all that structure with `as.matrix`?

```
mode(as.matrix(d))
[1] "character"
```

What happens if we do that to any old dataframe?

```
mode(as.matrix(data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
[1] "character"
mode(as.matrix(data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = factor(letters[1:10]))))
[1] "character"
mode(as.matrix(data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = 1:10)))
[1] "numeric"
```

The matrix is coerced to character if there are columns of numeric and character or factor.

This has absolutely nothing to do with `RODBC`.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed very helpful. But some questions remain. F13, F14 and F15 all contain strings as well as numbers. For some reason, only F15 is interpreted as character, while F13 and F14 are not – this I suppose is related to `RODBC`. Furthermore, I have to coerce the result to numeric in some way, since I am interested in the numbers, not in the descriptions. However, as `as.numeric(sub(",",".",x))` is a working workaround, I can happily proceed with my calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your issue using R-2.13.0 and RODBC_1.3-2.

```
> channel <- odbcConnectExcel("C:/test2.xls")
> (foo <- sqlQuery(channel, 'select F13, F14, F15 from "Wien2008$"'))
            F13          F14        F15
22           NA           NA         NA
23           NA           NA         NA
24           NA           NA         NA
25 7.730711e+01 1.958429e+01 12.6386753
26 4.126044e+01 1.045255e+01  6.7455280
27 4.293419e+01 1.087656e+01  7.0191636
28 4.278764e+01 1.083944e+01  6.9952058
29 4.073317e+01 1.031897e+01  6.6593269
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.13.0
```

Since I can't replicate the issue, I'm not sure how to help...  You say you didn't update any R files; does that mean you didn't change any of your *programs*?  Have you upgraded your R installation and/or upgraded any packages?